# Create Password field @html.TextBoxFor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Model  class

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Pass word is required")]
//[ValidatePasswordLength]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
//[Display(Name = "Password")]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

view

```
<div class="editor-label">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Password, new {@class="form-control",placeholder="Password" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)

</div>
```

I googled it.I found to use `@html.Editor` instead of @html.TextBoxFor but i have to  apply css for textbox .

I used  `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Password, new {@class="form-control",placeholder="Password" })` but css not applied.
How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If your MVC version is new enough, then

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new {@class="form-control", placeholder="Password"}})
```

Otherwise

```
@Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password, new {@class="form-control", placeholder="Password"})
```

Answer (score 18):

You can still use @Html.TextBoxFor:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Password, new {@class="form-control", placeholder="Password", @type = "password" })
```

Answer (score 14):

I also got the same problem and already used the code below but I have no idea why it didn't work

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new {@class="form-control", placeholder="Password"}})
```

but then I found the solution that is to add `type ="password"` into code above

then, the code is now

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new {@class="form-control", placeholder="Password", Type="password"}})
```

**update**
I've found another way to fix that is that is just add data annotation to Password property in LoginViewModel

```
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
public String Password { get; set; }
```

and in the view page just type this code

```
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new {@class="form-control", placeholder="Password"}})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using html `input type`

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Password, new {@class="form-control", placeholder="Password", @type = "password" })
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also working-

```
@Html.Password("Passwordvalue", null, new {@class="form-control", @id= "Passwordvalue", 
placeholder = "Password"})
```